# Firebase don' update my changes on my custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I am using Cloud Run to run my app and I have it connected whit firebase, today I update a new version on Cloud Run, all perfect, I go to the URL and all my changes there are whit any problem, but when I go to my custom domain, I see the old version of my website broke, without CSS
I wear it because when I go to the link that CLoud RUn gives me, there is the new version without problems

Comment: When posting a problem, please provide details such as your code, the configuration, how you are testing, errors/results, and what you expect to happen. As written, we could only guess. Read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried force refreshing your cache?
When you update a site and you see the active changes on some of it's URL access points but not all indicate that there is a cache in the middle. you can force clear your browser cache with F5, but if you are using a DNS cache like Cloud Flare, you will have to manually dump the cache from their services as well.